# How to change like button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new in jquery and ajax, I'd like to receive some help.

How could I add in this jquery code:

```
 $('.btn-likes').on('click', function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('liked');
       });
```

this logic?

```
function addLikes(id,action) {
    $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' #rating').val((index+1));
        if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').index(obj)) {
            return false;   }});
    $.ajax({
    url: "add_likes.php",
    data:'id='+id+'&action='+action,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='LoaderIcon.gif' />");},
    success: function(data){
    var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+id).val());
    switch(action) {
        case "like":
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'unlike\')" />');
        likes = likes+1;break;
        case "unlike":
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'like\')" />')
        likes = likes-1;break;}
    $('#likes-'+id).val(likes);
    if(likes>0) {
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
    } else {$('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html('');}}});
}
```

I need it for changing button animation style.
Thanks.

Comment: cut/paste the large blob into the smaller one?

Comment: I'd like to change "like animation" from this code : http://phppot.com/jquery/facebook-style-like-unlike-using-php-jquery/  like this http://codepen.io/dubstrike/pen/wMBjLz

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass jquery method is used to add/remove classes to the jquery selectors. Create a class which you need to toggle first and then use toggleClass for a jquery selector. If you need to check whether the class has been applied already or not, you can use hasClass jquery method.

Answer (score 0):

I added a line of code where you should do the adding of the appropriate class. Specifically:

```
  if (likes > 0) {
    // Do addClass here
    $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)").addClass('likes');
  } else {
    $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html('');
  }
```

The full code here, nicely indented:

```
function addLikes(id,action) {
  $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#tutorial-'+id+' #rating').val((index+1));
    if (index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').index(obj)) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "add_likes.php",
    data:'id='+id+'&action='+action,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='LoaderIcon.gif' />");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+id).val());
      switch(action) {
        case "like":
          $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'unlike\')" />');
          likes = likes+1;break;
        case "unlike":
          $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'like\')" />')
        likes = likes-1;break;
      }
      $('#likes-'+id).val(likes);
      if (likes > 0) {
        // Do addClass here
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)").addClass('likes');
      } else {
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html('');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Animations in AngularJS are meant to be used another way.

There are 4 types of animation events

- enter
- leave
- move
- add/remove class

If you want to do it the 'Angular way' with javascript, then what you want to do is hook into these events.

What you want to target in this case is the button like this:

(From the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

`myModule.animation('.slide', [function() {
  return {
    // make note that other events (like addClass/removeClass)
    // have different function input parameters
    enter: function(element, doneFn) {
      jQuery(element).fadeIn(1000, doneFn);

      // remember to call doneFn so that angular
      // knows that the animation has concluded
    },

    move: function(element, doneFn) {
      jQuery(element).fadeIn(1000, doneFn);
    },

    leave: function(element, doneFn) {
      jQuery(element).fadeOut(1000, doneFn);
    }
  }
}]`

In order to hook into an event on-click, then `enter`, `leave` and `move` won't do you much good; what you want is to add or remove a class name on the click event. You would could add the class in a number of ways, but here's one example:

`<button ng-class="{'my-animation':model.animationOn}" ng-click="model.animationOn=true">My Button Text</button>`

You'd have to remove the class at some point, though. The most appropriate time would probably be in the callback for that event using Angular's animation API. Something like this:

`myModule.animation('.my-btn', [function() {
  return {
    addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
      if(className == 'my-animation') {
        jQuery(element).fadeIn(1000, function() {
          doneFn(); // always call this when you're done
          element.removeClass('my-btn');
        });
      }
    }
  }
}]`

**Also**, in order for Angular to know about you adding and removing classes in javascript, you have to use one of the directives that ship with Angular, or use the `$animate` service in angular. In your first code example, you are adding a class using jQuery, but Angular will not know about it.